# mousse with liquid in bottom

Tags: soy, mousse, low-fat

I made 2 mousses. One typical and one was an attempt for something new. Both turned out with liquid in the bottom. I made both with egg whites. Did I not beat the egg whites enough?
The first was a simple passionfruit juice, unflavored gelatine, cream, and egg whites.
The second: Inspired by a chocolate mousse recipe, I made a base of cottage cheese blended for 5 min, stonyfield soy yogurt, and a pack of unflavored gelatine and slowly mixed with egg whites beaten in meringue with sugar. The next day the intended mousse was fine at the top but had a base of water. What did I do wrong? How could I improve it to make it better? Is the problem lack of fat?